# If $f(x)\xrightarrow{x\to a+}0$ and $f'\ne0$ in $(a,b)$, is $f(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in(a,a+\delta)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$ and $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable. Assume $$f(x)\xrightarrow{x\to a+}0\tag1$$ and $$f'(x)\ne0\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in(a,b).\tag2$$ Is this enough to ensure that there is a $\delta\in(0,b-a]$ such that $f(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in(a,a+\delta)$?

This is of course easy to show if $f'$ has a continuous extension at $a$, but I struggle to show this without this additional assumption.

Answer (score 4):

Since you never have $f'(x)=0$; it follows from [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) that either you always have $f'(x)>0$ or you always have $f'(x)<0$. In both case, $f$ is strictly monotonic. So, since $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=0$, there are no zeros of $f$ in $(a,b)$.